# Denied by policy! - answer from the server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, response

I've tried to submit the form using POST method and got the following response:

**Headers**

```
Connection          close
Content-Length      47
Pragma              "no-cache"
```

**Body**

```
<html>
<body>
Denied by policy!
</body>
</html>
```

The server is Apache. The form implemented on Wordpress CMS.
Why does it happen? Any ideas please. Unfortunatelly, I don't have the access to the server logs.

Comment: Are you POSTing cross domain?

Comment: @JonStirling The form is submitting on the same domain.

Comment: And the same subdomain? (Keeping in mind that www is a subdomain)

Comment: @JonStirling Yeah, exactly the same domain

Comment: Then I think you're stuck having to talk to your hosting provider I'm afraid.